# Use Random Number To Change HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

> What is wrong with this JavaScript? It should work, but after testing it, it does not! What am I doing wrong? When I test this in Chrome the console errors are: "index.html:129 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" and "index.html:43 Uncaught TypeError: response is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" What is the fix to these errors in relation to the script below?

```
<style>
body {
background-color: black;
font-family: 'courier new';
}
.yellow {
font-family: 'courier new';
font-weight: bold;
color: yellow;
}
.red {
font-family: 'courier new';
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
}
.green { 
font-family: 'courier new';
font-weight: bold;
color: green;
}
h1, .h2 {
color: white;
font-family: 'courier new';
}
p, h2 {
color: white;
font-family: 'courier new';
line-height: 150%;
}
button {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>8-Ball</h1>
<p>These are the normal answers you'd expect from an 8-ball! 
<br>Ask a yes or no question and 
<button onclick="response()">Refresh!</button>
for a different answer.</p>
<h2 class="h2" id="response"></h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
function response(){
var randnum;
randnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
//8-ball Icosahedron Answers
if (randnum == 1) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Signs point to yes.";
}
if (randnum == 2) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Yes.";
}
if (randnum == 3) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "yellow");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Reply hazy, try again.";
}
if (randnum == 4) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Without a doubt.";
}
if (randnum == 5) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "red");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "My sources say no.";
}
if (randnum == 6) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "As I see it, yes.";
}
if (randnum == 7) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "You may rely on it.";
}
if (randnum == 8) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "yellow");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Concentrate and ask again.";
}
if (randnum == 9) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "yellow");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Outlook not so good.";
}
if (randnum == 10) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "It is decidedly so.";
}
if (randnum == 11) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "yellow");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Better not tell you now.";
}
if (randnum == 12) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "red");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Very doubtful.";
}
if (randnum == 13) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Yes - definitely.";
}
if (randnum == 14) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "It is certain.";
}
if (randnum == 15) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "yellow");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Cannot predict now.";
}
if (randnum == 16) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Most likely.";
}
if (randnum == 17) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "yellow");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Ask again later.";
}
if (randnum == 18) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "red");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "My reply is no.";
}
if (randnum == 19) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "green");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Outlook good.";
}
if (randnum == 20) {
document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", "yellow");
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Don\'t count on it.";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're creating your random number in `randnumber`, the first 2 `if`statements work fine (setting class and text), the others suddenly have the undefined variable `randnum` in the condition, don't set any class attribute or innerHTML (only log to the console).... Investigate what's different between the first 2 if's and the other 17 and you'll be on your way...

Comment: So, you're saying if I format the rest of the script the same way as the first 2? The script will work?

Comment: why don't you check the answer? I put an effort to write your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use same variable, one of these `randnum` or `randnumber`:

Here is working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/baLbLxse/

**FOR BETTER EXPERIENCE:**

1) You better use only numbers, not like `'3'`;

2) why don't you use array? You can store all in array and get array element with random index like this, `answers[randnum]`:

```
 var answers = [
      {
        color: 'green',
        text: "Signs point to yes."
      },
      {
        color: 'green',
        text: "Yes."
      },
      ...
     ];

function response() {
    var randnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * answers.length));
    //8-Ball Icosahedron Answers
    document.getElementById("response").setAttribute("class", answers[randnum].color);
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = answers[randnum].text;
  }
```

Recommended version is here: https://jsfiddle.net/baLbLxse/3/

Comment: Minor suggestion: Might aswell use `answers.length` instead of hardcoding `20`.

Comment: Yes Right! Thanks